# the method getsystemservice(string) is undefined for the type MyReciever

Tags: android, eclipse, alarm

I`m trying to make an Android alarm application, but i´m gettin the follow error:

The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type MyReceiver

The code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {

      Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
      r.play();
      Toast.makeText(context, "Ud tiene pico y placa hoy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


       Notification n = new NotificationCompat.Builder (context)
       .setContentTitle("Pico Y Placa")
       .setContentText("Mensaje")
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
       .setAutoCancel(true).build();

       NotificationManager notificationManager = 
       (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       notificationManager.notify(0, n); 


  }

  }
```

If you could let me know what I'm doing wrong here that would be great!

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, it was:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = 
   (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```